# Annual effective rate of interest

Tags: actuarial-science

> Galileo deposits 15,000 in a bank. During the first year, the bank
>   credits an annual effective rate of interest i. For the second year,
>   the bank credits an annual effective rate of interest (i-5%). At the
>   end of two years, he has 18,093.75 in the bank. What would Galileo
>   have in the bank at the end of three years, if the annual effective
>   rate of interest were (i+9%) for each of the three years?

I'm a first-year student of Actuarial Science, and I tried to look for example question from my university depository. Out of 5 questions, this is the only one I can't think off on how to solve for the ***annual effective rate of interest***.

Can somebody give me ideas on how to start or to solve for this problem?

Comment: Please explain where ths problem is giving you difficulty?

Comment: @marshalcraft, for the understanding and the calculation itself. I'm actually on the first week of this course, pardon me for the lack of explanations!

Comment: Ok, that is fine. Can you explain explicitly what approach to solving the problem you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

$(15000(i+1))(i+.95)=18093.75$ solve for $i$.

The principle after the first year is $15000(i+1)$. This is used now to compute the principle after the second year the same way except we get $.05$ less interest.

You basically get a quadratic equation which will have 2 solutions but we need only one.

$15000(i^2+1.95i+.95)=18093.75$

$i^2+1.95i+.95=1.20625$

$i^2+1.95i-.25625=0$.

You can use the quadratic equation to solve this, which should be readily apparent hopefully,

$i=\frac{-1.95 \pm \sqrt{1.95^2+4(.25625)}}{2}$

$i=\frac{-1.95 \pm 2.197}{2}=- .975\pm 1.0985$

Possible values

$i={.1235,-2.02735}$

But you need $0 \le i \le 1$ so the interest rate was $.1235$.

**note** should double check answer.

Answer (score 1):

The amount in the bank after one year is $15000(1+i)$ since $i$ is the effective annual rate for the first year. Since $i-0.05$ is the effective rate for the second year, after two years the account will be at $$15000(1+i)(1+i-0.05) = 18093.75.$$ You can solve this for $i.$